# ubuntu server not seeing entire system disc

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu 22.04 server on a machine which has 2 nvme drives, one 2TB and one 4TB. Ubuntu is installed on the 2TB nvme. But for some unknown reason it is NOT seeing the entire disc. I have tried everything I can think of, including reformatting (low format with dd), installing windows 10 then removing the partitions and reinstalling ubuntu and still it is not seeing more than 200 GIG. I need the main disc to have the maximum 1.x TB. Why is it not seeing it? See image here: https://www.a7q.com/i.png showing A: the 2TB nvme, B) the 4TH nvme and C) the 2TB nvme installed with ubuntu but only making 83G available for use! Why is this happening? Can someone give me the solution to this strange problem? This has never happened before. Yesterday this machine has a 2TB SSD which I removed and replaced with a 2 TB nvme, now I get this problem. Why? When I install postgresSQL it installs on the 83G partition and there is not enough room for loading the data. I need to be able to access the entire 2 TB system disc (nvme).

Comment: SO is for programming problems. Please try asking at [askubntu.com](https://askubntu.com) or [superuser.com](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com)